# Convert an integer value to a string with an enum as basis

Tags: c++, type-conversion, poker, playing-cards

I have been learning C++ for a few weeks and I am now trying to program a little thing by myself and practice what I learned at the same time.

So my program is a poker hand distributor.

I started by creating a simple "card" class which contains two methods, value and suit.

At first I tried to do an enum for both, but I couldn't set the enum with integers (for example`enum value {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,T,J,Q,K,A}` doesn't work, which is normal.

My enum for suits works just fine, it's just that when I want to print a card (i implemented `operator<<` in my class) I don't know how to convert my integers to the corresponding suits. I will get for example 10 1 for ten of spades. I would like to know how to convert this in my `operator<<()` function to get something like `T s` when I want to print a card using `cout << card` which contains the informations 10 and 1

;

;

**tldr** I want to know how to convert for example "10 1" to "T s (T spades)"
while keeping 2 to 9 as such (9 1->9 s)

Thank you!!

Comment: Just curious, why do you want 2...9 to be numbers but 10 to be a letter, since in cards it is a number as well?

Comment: @KillzoneKid common abbreviation for single character notation.

Comment: @KillzoneKid IIRC, in some places (e.g. France) it is a letter. Remember, your culture is not the only one ;)

Comment: I'm French and I have never seen a T on a card game. But you are right that's not the question.

Comment: I just want to smooth things up since I'm still programming in console so I can sort a card board with dedicated space of 2 characters per card. Indeed when I play there is a "10" on my cards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know how to convert for example "10 1" to "T s (T spades)" while keeping 2 to 9 as such (9 1->9 s)

You can use couple of arrays to map the numbers to strings.

```
std::string valueMap[13] = {"A", "2", ..., "Q", "K"};
std::string suitMap[4] = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
```

Assuming you use an `enum` with values 1-13 for the value and an `enum` with values 1-4 for the suit, you can use `valueMap[value-1]` to get the string for the value and use `suitMap[suit-1]` to get the string for the suit.

Comment: This solution is indeed better. If you use an enum, you can't directly use the names you put in your enum. Only the compiler knows them, they are implicitly associated to numbers in the final program. Using an enum you would have to create a function implementing a `switch(...) { ... }` to return the corresponding value. With the solution above you can just use directly the string.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois This is compatible with enums.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I used, plus an int to string function that convert the int to valueMap[int-1]. I did not think to use the numbers as strings. I guess it will come with time! Thank you again.

Comment: @Tommy-XavierRobillard, you are welcome. Glad I was able to help. Yes, you will learn the tricks of the trade as time goes by :)

Comment: @FeiXiang Yes it is compatible with enum, but if you want to output a string having the same name as your enum entries, you have to associate them by hand, you can't use the name as it is.